# Android Fragment for Slider Menu which has Fragments inside for Tabs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, multiple-inheritance, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to create a fragment, for an activity which I already created, that contains tabs.
The tabs have been implemented using fragments, and the class has been extended for fragment activity.

I have searched online and so far, what I have found is that this might not be possible, and that there exists no android app [Well, that I know of] that implements this.

```
  package com.example.userinterface;

  import com.example.userinterface.adapter.TabPagerAdapter;

  import android.app.ActionBar;
  import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

 public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    //Declaration of resources to be used
    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "All", "Zone A", "Zone B" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_section);

    // Initialisation
    Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar = getActionBar();
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
            }
    );

    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

    //Set the action bar
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    //Enable tabs on action Bar and add a listener
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Return the current position of the tab in the action bar
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }
    };
    // Adding Tabs
     actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[0]).setTabListener(tabListener)) ;
     actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[1]).setTabListener(tabListener)) ;    
     actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[2]).setTabListener(tabListener)) ;
}
```

}

Any tips or links or examples to understand would be very much appreciated, as I'm still learning the basics in Android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swapable tabs in Slider Menu fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678513/swapable-tabs-in-slider-menu-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the following reference links can help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/