# Swapable tabs in Slider Menu fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-navigation, android-sliding

I have implemented Navigation Drawer by Referring [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and now what I want to do is to display swiping tabs inside a fragment. i.e. when i click on an item in navigation drawer, lets say the first one, it should display swiping tabs for that items.( I have 6 fragments in my list view.(likewise :- A,B,C,D,E,F). and I need 3 swapable tabs on my A Fragment.)

If the item1 is Events, when i click on it, then it should display swiping tabs.

But I am facing the following issues:-

1. How can I implement view pager inside fragment?
2. It is possible that a fragment extends a fragment.
3. when A fragment is extending a FragmentActivity, then in my main activity, code is showing an error saying "type mismatch", can't convert from A Fragment to fragment.

This is my Deep.java file

```
    package com.amar.demo;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Deep extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deep);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.a_More:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.a_More).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            // fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            // .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

In this code i am facing problem in case 0.

This is my HomeFragment code :-
        package com.amar.demo;

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.amar.demo.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;

public class HomeFragment extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "My Restaurant", "Offers", "Search & Book",
            "News & Updates" };

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);
        // code of tabes
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

this is my deep.xml code :-

```
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my homefragment.xml code :-

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: yeah .. we can implement view pager inside a fragment...

Comment: But..How can i implement view pager inside a fragment...??

Comment: @Amardeep see my answer, I've update the answer with the new code.

Comment: Not sure how far back you need to support older versions of Android, but subclassing FragmentActivity has long been deprecated, just need to subclass normal Activity now (not sure the version cutoff for this).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must create a fragment with a custom layout that contains a ViewPager on it.

Follow these steps, it will guide in the entire process.

### 1. Create the layout to represent the ViewPager, name it fragment_main.xml

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

### 2. Create a fragment to hold the ViewPager declared on the XML above, name it MyFragment.java

As you can see, we declare the `TabHost` the `ViewPager` and other elements declared in the XML above. Also in this fragment we inflate the layout created before, and a `TabAdapter` to handle all the tabs.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public static class MyFragment extends Fragment
{

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    public MyFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
    {
        super.onCreate(instance);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), mTabHost, mViewPager);

        // Here we load the content for each tab. 
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("One"), PageOneFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("Two"), PageTwoFragment.class, null);

        return v;
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
    {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo
        {
            private final String tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
            {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
        {
            private final Context mContext;

            public DummyTabFactory(Context context)
            {
                mContext = context;
            }

            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager)
        {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
        {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);

            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

        }

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
        {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, each tab calls a specific fragment. These fragments represent the content for each tab. So let's create them, they are very simple, and contains only a `TextView`.

### 3. Create a fragment for the first tab content, name it PageOneFragment.java

This fragment will hold the content of the first tab. You can put anything inside this fragment, it will live separated from the other fragments and from the other tabs.

Here we inflate the xml layout pageone_fragment.xml inside the `onCreateView` method. We will create this xml layout in the next step.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PageOneFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pageone_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

We must create the layout for this fragment as we mentioned before.

### 4. Create the layout for the PageOneFragment, name it pageone_fragment.xml

This is just a simple layout with a `TextView` to represent the content of the tab. You can build anything you want inside this layout, it will live separated from the other fragments and tabs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ff4063ff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="First Page"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/firstFragmentTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As we have two tabs, we have two fragments, one for each tab. So let's create the second fragment for the second tab content.

### 5. Create the fragment for the second tab content, name it PageTwoFragment.java

As you can see, we inflate a different layout on the `onCreateView` method, it's called `pagetwo_fragment.xml`. We will create it on the next step.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PageTwoFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagetwo_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

And as we did before for the PageOneFragment, let's create the layout for the second fragment too, as we mentioned before.

### 6. Create the layout for the PageTwoFragment, name it pagetwo_fragment.xml

This is a simple layout with a single `TextView`, just to represent the content. You can build anything you want in here, it will live separated from the other fragments and tabs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ff4063ff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Second Page"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/firstFragmentTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### 7. Call this fragment from your `NavigationDrawer`

If you want to call this fragment from your `NavigationDrawer`, inside the `switch` statement on your activity's `displayView(int position)` method, you should do this in one of your `case` statements, for example.

```
case 0:
    fragment = new MyFragment();
    break;
```

### Here is the final result

A `ViewPager` running on a fragment, with two tabs each contains a unique fragment with a unique content.

[image]

That's it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is a suggestion...i hope ..,you know where to write answer and where to write a suggestion

Comment: @GVSharma I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I have found the error in step 7 "Type mismatch: cannot convert from HomeFragment to Fragment"

Comment: private void displayView(int position) {
  // update the main content by replacing fragments
  Fragment fragment = null;
  switch (position) {
  case 0:
   fragment = new HomeFragment();
   break;

Comment: No.. you have to call `MyFragment`, not `HomeFragment`. What is the name of the fragment class you created?

Comment: @Amardeep the ViewPager fragment must extend `Fragment`, not `FragmentActivity`. As you can see in my code, the `MyFragment` class extends `Fragment`.

Comment: I have implemented your code and it is working fine. But when I am using the code in Slider Navigation then the point No 7. is showing an error saying Type Mismatch.

So.. What is that I can do to rectify it.

And also, give me your email id so that I can share my code with you.
Thanks and looking forward for your reply.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53815/discussion-between-rogcg-and-amardeep)

Comment: @rogcg:I am getting problem when i got with other sliding menus and return to my main menus which is having Tabs it getting problem tht  the layout cannot be displayed that will inside the fragment of tab.

Comment: @rogcg how to pass context from Myfragment to PageOneFragment.class

Comment: @Amardeepvijay use this code in onCreateView
context = container.getContext();

Comment: @rogcg: When I go to other fragments and return to this fragment. The sliding tabs malfunction. What may be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

**For error in step 7 "Type mismatch**

make it:

```
replace **import android.app.Fragment** to **import android.support.v4.app.Fragment**
```

and in case:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
>         {
>             tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
>             String tag = tabSpec.getTag();
>
>             TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
>             mTabs.add(info);
>             mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
>             notifyDataSetChanged();
>         }
> ```

where declaration of mTabs variable

thanks